# Azure Web Apps Website copies/replicates the disk file or share common folder

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

We are using  ASP.NET CMS which uses the Lucene index. As we know Lucene indexes are nothing but a files located under physical drive.

I'm quiet new to web apps. I'm aware that we can FTP and make changes to the files etc.

What I don't know is below:

1. Does each files we FTP gets replicated to each instances or shared from common folder?
2. If we scale up or down, what exactly happens on back end? Files gets copied or website gets created in IIS and uses the same shared folder?
3. If instance is down, how does azure Spins new instance i.e. which deployment packages does it use?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK all the instances of an Azure web site use the same file-system.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Web Apps has a shared file system that all instances of your web app use.  So, to question #1, there is no replication from one instance to another.

For question #2, it is the latter - the web app instance uses the same share folder that the rest of the web app instances use.

For question #3, the files are actually stored in a Azure Storage behind the scenes.  So, if your instance were to go down, it is able to re-initialize using the shared file system backed by Azure storage.